# How do I nest layout managers without using swing classes/methods?

Tags: java, applet, awt, layout-manager, java-6

I need to make an applet in Java 6, 640*480 pixels, with a toolbar on the bottom with some buttons, scrollbars, and labels. The best way I could think of was using a `BorderLayout`, making the `BorderLayout.SOUTH` region a `GridBagLayout` (which would contain the controls), and the rest of the `BorderLayout` area null, as a place for grapics to be drawn with the controls. I can't find any resources online that don't use swing, and I don't know anything about swing to deduce what they are doing or how to translate it into awt code. Here is where I am now. The code ends abruptly in `init()`, since that's where the layout mangers start. Thank you for any help you have. Let me know if you need more information then what is here.

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Bounce extends Applet implements ActionListener, AdjustmentListener
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Graphics page;
    //buttons
    String shapeButtonText = "Square";
    Button shape = new Button(shapeButtonText);
    Button quit = new Button("Quit");
    Button run = new Button("Run");
    Button tail = new Button("Tail");
    Button clear = new Button("Clear");

    //labels
    Label speedLabel = new Label("Speed", Label.CENTER);
    Label sizeLabel = new Label("Size", Label.CENTER);

    //scrollbars
    private final int barHeight = 20;
    private final int SLIDER_WIDTH = 10;
    private final int MAXSPEED = 110;
    private final int MINSPEED = 0;
    private final int UNIT_INC = 1;
    private final int BLOC_INC = 10;
    private final int MAX_SIZE = 110;
    private final int MIN_SIZE = 10;
    Scrollbar speedBar = new Scrollbar(Scrollbar.HORIZONTAL, MINSPEED, SLIDER_WIDTH, 0, MAXSPEED);  
    Scrollbar sizeBar = new Scrollbar(Scrollbar.HORIZONTAL, MIN_SIZE, SLIDER_WIDTH, 0, MAX_SIZE);


    //methods   
    public void init()
    {
        //set up objects
        //speed scroll bar
        speedBar.setUnitIncrement(UNIT_INC);
        speedBar.setBlockIncrement(BLOC_INC);
        speedBar.setValue(MAXSPEED/2);

        //size scrollbar
        sizeBar.setUnitIncrement(UNIT_INC);
        sizeBar.setBlockIncrement(BLOC_INC);
        sizeBar.setValue(MAX_SIZE/2);

        //draw the window
        BorderLayout window = new BorderLayout();
        GridBagLayout toolbar = new GridBagLayout();
        //?
    }

    public void start()
    {
    }

    public void run()
    {
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
    }

    public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e)
    {
    }

    public void stop()
    {
    }

    public void destory()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the error message. You need to bring up the Java Control Panel for your browser plugin to see it.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use Swing? AWT is considered obsolete in most Java circles.

Comment: @Code-Guru there is no error message. I just plain don't know how, and cant find other resources. Reason for not using swing? No good reason, but at the moment I only know some AWT and no Swing, so i was just sticking with what I know

Comment: looking around and seeing no AWT stuff leads me to believe I should bite the bullet and teach myself swing for this though...

Comment: I strongly suggest you learn Swing. Much of it is built on top of AWT, so it is very similar. As for the error message, there is one somewhere. It's been a while since I made applets, so I can't remember exactly how to pull it up...

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12886783/how-do-i-view-error-messages-for-my-java-applet/12886784#12886784 for instructions on how to see the error messages. Then copy and paste them here.

Comment: @Code-Guru i did, and there is no error.

Comment: After looking more closely at your code, I see that it shouldn't stop. However, you haven't added any controls to your applet, so you'll get a blank window.

Comment: yes, theres nothing added since I dont know how to get the layout managers to arrange as needed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's clarify a few things. A `LayoutManager`s are used by a `Container` (such as `Frame`, `Panel`, or `Applet`) to calculate position and size of the components inside the `Container`. This means that it is incorrect to talk about "nesting `LayoutManager`s". On the other hand you can nest `Container`s inside each other and give each one its own `LayoutManager`. I believe this is what you want to do.

Let me illustrate this with a contrived example:

```
public class MyGUI {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frame f = new Frame("Layout Example");
        Panel mainPanel = new Panel(new BorderLayout());
        f.add(mainPanel);

        Panel toolBar = new Panel(new FlowLayout());
        toolBar.add(new Button("Button 1"));
        toolBar.add(new Button("Button 2"));
        mainPanel.add(tollBar.NORTH);

        Panel statusBar = new Panel(new FlowLayout());
        statusBar.add(new Label("Status"));
        mainPanel.add(statusBar);

        f.pack();
        f.show();
    }
}
```

Notice that you need to create a new `Panel` for each `LayoutManager`. Or rather each `Panel` that you create needs a `LayoutManager`.  Also, this example can easily be changed from AWT to Swing by replacing `Frame` with `JFrame`, `Panel` with `JPanel`, `Button` with `JButton`, and `Label` with `JLabel`.

p.s. The above code is not tested. It should illustrate the concepts involved here, though.

Comment: this makes much more sense then what my previous thought process was.